# "Illegal parameter number" errors, in a macro for writing macro definitions to a file

Tags: macros, write

**Problem.**

I'm trying to write a command similar to `\newcommand`, but I'm having problems with *illegal parameter numbers*: for reasons that I can't fix out, it's asking me to use parameters of the type `##1` rather than `#1`. I'm familiar with using the former in the case of nested definitions, *e.g.* in code-snippets such as `\def\foo#1{\def\bar##1{#1-##1}}`; but I don't understand why the error is coming up in what I'm trying to do. I'm hoping that someone can show me how to make parameters of the style `#1` suffice, in the example I describe below.

**Details.**

I'm trying to write a macro called `\newmacro`, which emulates the syntax of `\newcommand`, and which makes each macro write its own definition to an output file the first time it is used. Try out the minimal example below to see precisely what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newwrite\macro@outfile
\immediate\openout\macro@outfile=\jobname.macros%
\typeout{Writing extra macros to file \jobname.macros}%

\def\macro@write#1#2{%
    \immediate\write\macro@outfile{\string\renewcommand\string#1#2}%
    \renewcommand#1#2%
    #1%
}

\def\newmacro#1[#2]#3{%
    \def#1{\macro@write{#1}{[#2]{#3}}}}

\makeatother
```

These macro definitions don't quite work properly: for instance, using the above pre-amble, the second invocation of `\newmacro` below throws an error.

```
\begin{document}

\newmacro\testmacro[1]{foo(##1)}
\testmacro{1}
\testmacro{2}

\newmacro\testmacro[1]{foo --- #1 ---}
\testmacro{3}
\testmacro{4}

\end{document}
```

If this document is compiled with the preamble above as `test.tex`, in addition to the usual output, a new file `test.macros` is created which will have the following content:

```
\renewcommand\testmacro[1]{foo(##1)}
\renewcommand\testmacro[1]{foo --- ##1 ---}
```

This is almost correct, and it is what I mean by the macro writing "its own definition" to an output file. However, I would like the stored definitions to use the parameters `#1` rather than `##1`, and for the invocation of `\newmacro` with the parameter `#1` not to throw errors. I'm hoping that someone can show me how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say:

```
\newmacro\testmacro[1]{foo --- #1 ---}
```

You end up with:

```
\def\testmacro{\macro@write{\testmacro}{[1]{foo --- #1 ---}}}}
```

So you try to define a macro without any arguments but still use `#1` in it. This leads to the `Illegal parameter number` error message.

In order to permit `#1`, `#2`, etc. you would need to define the macro with the right number of arguments. You can define the macro first with nine arguments to avoid any `Illegal parameter number` error. Then you expand it with `##1` etc. as arguments, so you basically replace `#1` with `##1`, etc., and define this to the same macro but without arguments. Because all this happens inside another macro `\newmacro` all `#` must be doubled:

```
\def\newmacro#1[#2]#3{%
    \def#1##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9{\macro@write{#1}{[#2]{#3}}}% Define macro in a safe way
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1{####1}{####2}{####3}{####4}{####5}{####6}{####7}{####8}{####9}}% Replace `#1` with `##1` etc.
}
```

Then, however, you have the issues of `##` in your output file. This can be best avoided by again defining the macro with nine arguments and print the `\meaning` with the prefix stripped, before defining it to its true definition:

```
\def\macro@write#1#2{%
    \def#1##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9{#2}%
    \immediate\write\macro@outfile{\string\renewcommand\string#1\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}%
    \renewcommand#1#2%
    #1%
}
```

The `\jobname.macros` files then holds:

```
\renewcommand\testmacro[1]{foo(#1)}
\renewcommand\testmacro[1]{foo --- #1 ---}
```

However, this breaks when you now use `##1` inside the macro definition, e.g:

```
\newmacro\testmacro[1]{foo --- #1 ---\def\A##1{(##1)}}
```

---

So instead you would recommend the following approach: Define the macro to a different name and copy that definition to the real name inside `\macro@write`. You avoid thereby all issues with escaping of macro arguments.
You can use `\csname` with `\string#1` to build a second macro name which is unique to the official macro name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newwrite\macro@outfile
\immediate\openout\macro@outfile=\jobname.macros%
\typeout{Writing extra macros to file \jobname.macros}%

\def\newmacro#1[#2]#3{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname @\string#1\endcsname[#2]{#3}%
    \newcommand#1{\macro@write{#1}{#2}}%
}

\def\macro@write#1#2{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname @\string#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\csname @\string#1\endcsname\@undefined
    \immediate\write\macro@outfile{\string\newcommand\string#1[#2]{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}}%
    #1%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newmacro\testmacroa[1]{foo(#1)}
\testmacroa{1}
\testmacroa{2}

\newmacro\testmacrob[1]{foo --- #1 ---}
\testmacrob{3}
\testmacrob{4}

\newmacro\testmacroc[1]{foo --- #1 ---\def\A##1{(##1)}}
\testmacroc{3}
\testmacroc{4}

\end{document}
```

I took the liberty to replace `\renewcommand` with `\newcommand` because its seems to be more logically for a `\newmacro` macro. If you really want `\renewcommand`, i.e. allow `\newmacro` to redefine its macro, then define `\newmacro` like:

```
\def\newmacro#1[#2]#3{%
    \expandafter\let\csname @\string#1\endcsname\empty
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname @\string#1\endcsname[#2]{#3}%
    \def#1{\macro@write{#1}{#2}}%
}
```

The first line ensures that the macro exists in any case before `\renewcommand` is used.

Comment: thank you for your thorough response! I'm attempting to refine your answer to one which will allow for optional arguments, while still writing the appropriate definition to the `*.macros` file — a task which is complicated by the way that `\newcommand` constructs macros which take optional arguments. In the meantime, I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Epilogue.**

As I noted in a comment to Martin's answer, there were additional obstacles which I found when I tried to extend my/his code to accept optional arguments in the style of `\newcommand`. I've accepted Martin's answer as resolving the problem which I posted: this answer is presented to show how to successfully treat both the cases of macros defined with `\newcommand`, both with optional arguments and without.

**Recovering and writing the intended meaning of the macro.**

The basic problem is that for macro `\cseq` which is meant to take an optional arguments, `\newcommand` defines two macros: `\cseq` itself, which looks for the optional argument, and `\\cseq` which actually operates on the arguments. So we need to do additional effort to extract the "meaning" of the `\cseq` for the purpose of writing to the file `\jobname.macros`.

We define a separate macro for "activating" a macro `\cseq` which is defined by `\newmacro` — giving `\cseq` its intended meaning, where it is temporarily stored in a macro `\macro@cseq`, while also extracting the "name" of the macro to `\@tempa`.

```
\def\macro@activate#1{%
    \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname macro@\@tempa\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\csname macro@\@tempa\endcsname\@undefined
}
```

We will assume that the name of the macro (*e.g.* `cseq`) is stored in `\@tempa` when we want to write the intended meaning of `\cseq` to the output file. The following command then constructs the command sequence `\macro@cseq`, which it stores as the new meaning of `\@tempa`. Using this, it then writes the meaning of `\\macro@cseq` (the macro which actually acts on the arguments of `\macro@cseq`) to output: the macro `\\macro@cseq` is constructed on the final line essentially as  `\csname\string\macro@cseq\endcsname`.

```
\def\macro@write@opts#1[#2][#3]{%
    \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\noexpand\csname macro@\@tempa\endcsname}%
    \def\@tempb##1{%
        \immediate\write\macro@outfile{\string\newcommand\string#1[#2][#3]{%
        \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning##1}}}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempb%
        \expandafter\csname\expandafter\string\@tempa\endcsname%
}
```

The corresponding command to write macros with no arguments, or with no optional arguments, is simpler. In the macro below, `#2` is either equal to the empty string or to `[numargs]`.

```
\def\macro@write@noopts#1#2{%
    \immediate\write\macro@outfile{%
        \string\newcommand\string#1#2{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}}%
}
```

**The initial definition of the self-activating macros.**

The remainder of the code is a more-or-less straightforward case analysis which determines if there are any parameters to the macro `\cseq` being defined, whether it has any optional arguments, and then redefining `\cseq` to activate (and write to file) it's intended behaviour before calling itself again. In the course of activating its intended behaviour, `\@tempa` comes to store the name of the macro (*e.g.* `cseq`), as we required in the case of a macro taking optional arguments.

```
\def\newmacro#1{%
    \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar [{\newmacro@args#1}{\newmacro@noopts#1{}}}

\def\newmacro@args#1[#2]{%
    \kernel@ifnextchar [{\newmacro@opts#1{[#2]}}{\newmacro@noopts#1{[#2]}}}

\def\newmacro@noopts#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname macro@\@tempa\endcsname#2{#3}%
    \def#1{%
        \macro@activate#1%
        \macro@write@noopts#1{#2}%
        #1}}

\def\newmacro@opts#1#2[#3]#4{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname macro@\@tempa\endcsname#2[#3]{#4}%
    \def#1{%
        \macro@activate#1%
        \macro@write@opts#1#2[#3]%
        #1}}
```

Thanks again to Martin for his help.